# Elixir Repo.insert_all/2 and unique constraint

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a rather interesting problem today. I'm trying to implement a bulk insert from CSV file into my database using the Ecto function `Repo.insert_all/2` however, one thing bothers me.

The problem is the following code in my context:

```
defmodule AppName.Roles do
  def bulk_insert(array_of_maps) do
    try do 
      Repo.insert_all(Role, array_of_maps)
    rescue
      exception in Postgrex.Error ->
        _handle_exception(exception) # or whatever
    end
  end
end
```

For now though, this seems like a **hack**. Since I know there's a built-in mechanism of changesets which do handle unique constraints, but I have no idea how to include that part of the system with `Repo.insert_all/3`

But since the `insert_all` function doesn't care about **changesets** it makes this even harder.

( I'm of course referring to `unique_constraint/2` )

I do know I can:

- Use `Multi` to perform this, but this creates **separate queries on the backend instead of doing it as a one big query**
- Keep the code using a `try rescue` block, but I'd like to see if there's a more Elixir-y way to solve this due to the philosophy of pattern matching and let it crash terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3-options) accepts a list of options, one of which is

> - `:on_conflict` — It may be one of `:raise` (the default), `:nothing`, `:replace_all`, `:replace_all_except_primary_key`, `{:replace, fields}`, a keyword list of update instructions or an [`Ecto.Query`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html) query for updates.

Usually whether one wants to handle conflicts, they do set that option to somewhat helpful instead of raising an exception.

Also `:conflict_target` option might be used to provide *unsafe fragments*.